# Silverlight average line in Columnseries

Tags: silverlight, line, charts, average

I have an Columnseries and now I want to display a line that shows the average of all Columns.
If I add a Lineseries, it's display next to the columnseries, not behind.

Any suggestions?

Thanks Juono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a line series that contains the same number of entries as the ColumnSeries and that has an identical set of IndependentValues, set the DependentValue to the same value average value.  If you want this to appear behind the ColumnSeries (seems a strange thing to do) you would make it the first series in the chart then have the ColumnSeries as the last series in the chart.